# Why are ToLookup and GroupBy different?

Tags: c#, linq

[`.ToLookup<TSource, TKey>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup) returns an [`ILookup<TKey, TSource>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.ilookup-2). `ILookup<TKey, TSource>` also implements interface `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`.

[`.GroupBy<TSource, TKey>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Tkey, TSource>>`.

ILookup has the handy indexer property, so it can be used in a dictionary-like (or lookup-like) manner, whereas GroupBy can't. GroupBy without the indexer is a pain to work with; pretty much the only way you can then reference the return object is by looping through it (or using another LINQ-extension method). In other words, any case that GroupBy works, ToLookup will work as well.

All this leaves me with the question why would I ever bother with GroupBy? Why should it exist?

Comment: `GroupBy` Is `IQuerable`, `ILookup` is not

Comment: GroupBy doesn't enumerate the list [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) enumerates it the same way ToList / ToArray

Comment: I've nominated this for reopening since the question it's allegedly a duplicate of is about *IGrouping* rather than *GroupBy* and *ILookup* rather than *ToLookup*. The differences between those are different to the differences between these. This should be apparent from the differences in the answers between the questions.

Comment: both of them create a `Lookup`, but `GroupBy` creates it when the result is enumerated https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d60d1015ac88b667

Answer (score 222, accepted):

> why would I ever bother with GroupBy? Why should it exist?

What happens when you call ToLookup on an object representing a remote database table with a billion rows in it?

The billion rows are sent over the wire, and you build the lookup table locally.

What happens when you call GroupBy on such an object?

A query object is built; end of story.

When that query object is enumerated then the analysis of the table is done *on the database server* and the grouped results are sent back *on demand* a few at a time.

Logically they are the same thing but the *performance implications* of each are completely different. Calling ToLookup means *I want a cache of the entire thing right now organized by group*.  Calling GroupBy means "I am building an object to represent the question 'what would these things look like if I organized them by group?'"

Comment: The poster doesn't specifically target an `IQueryable<T>` representation.  Your answer covers that situation, but when it's just plain ol `IEnumerable<T>` (LINQ-to-Objects) it can seem like there isn't a reason to use one over the other, which is what I believe @Shlomo is trying to get at.  *Not* the `IQueryable<T>` case, but the LINQ-to-Objects case.

Comment: It strikes me as beneficial for LINQ to be consistent, where possible.  I think demonstrating its usefulness in LINQ-to-SQL is sufficient to justify leaving it in LINQ-to-Objects.

Comment: @casperOne: I think you've failed to understand my point. Even in the LINQ-to-objects case, calling GroupBy *still* does not iterate over the collection. (As Aducci pointed out in the answer which you deleted.) That's a fundamental difference.

Comment: @EricLippert Fair enough, admittedly, I completely missed this.  Brain expulsion.

Comment: @EricLippert: But is that just a side effect of the implementation or is it *guaranteed* that the enumerable will be iterated when you call ToLookup, no matter what changes are made to the implementation?

Comment: @Will: You make an excellent point; the documentation does not guarantee that ToLookup is "eager". It probably should note that.

Comment: Eagerness explains it. The language of 'ToMetaType' I think implies eagerness; though it is obviously left up to the implementation. The other 'To's are all eager (ToList, ToArray, ToDictionary). Thanks guys.

Answer (score 131):

In simple LINQ-world words:

- `ToLookup()` - immediate execution
- `GroupBy()` - deferred execution

Answer (score 21):

The two are similar, but are used in different scenarios. `.ToLookup()` returns a ready to use object that already has all the groups (but not the group's content) eagerly loaded. On the other hand, `.GroupBy()` returns a lazy loaded sequence of groups.

Different LINQ providers may have different behaviors for the eager and lazy loading of the groups. With LINQ-to-Object it probably makes little difference, but with LINQ-to-SQL (or LINQ-to-EF, etc.), the grouping operation is performed on the database server rather than the client, and so you may want to do an additional filtering on the group key (which generates a `HAVING` clause) and then only get some of the groups instead of all of them. `.ToLookup()` wouldn't allow for such semantics since all items are eagerly grouped.