# Not able to understand the functionality of ToLookup linq extension method

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out the functionality of ToLookup method here in the code.It's using grouping somehow to return a list. Can somebody just tell me how this is working or just guide me in the right direction:

```
.ToLookup(
  c => new 
  {
      c.CoverageType.Code, 
      c.CoverageType.Mnemonic, 
      c.CoverageType.Description, 
      c.CoverageType.CoverageLevel, 
      c.CoverageType.CoveragePosition
  })
.Select(
  t => new CoverageOption
  {
    CoverageType =
      new CoverageType
      {
          Code = t.Key.Code, 
          Mnemonic = t.Key.Mnemonic, 
          Description = t.Key.Description, 
          CoverageLevel = t.Key.CoverageLevel, 
          CoveragePosition = t.Key.CoveragePosition
      },
    Limits =
      (from Coverage c in t select c.Limit).GroupBy(l => l.Code)
        .Select(gr => gr.First()), 
    Deductibles =
      (from Coverage c in t select c.Deductible).GroupBy(d => d.Code)
        .Select(gr => gr.First())
})
.OrderBy(t => t.CoverageType.CoveragePosition);
```

Comment: Which bit don't you understand? You use `ToLookup` to create a one to many dictionary (the lambda function is the key selector function). You can see this later in the select where you are using `t.Key...` in the select

Answer (score 1):

Source items (which I assume has type `Coverage`) are grouped by this key:

```
new 
{
  c.CoverageType.Code, 
  c.CoverageType.Mnemonic, 
  c.CoverageType.Description, 
  c.CoverageType.CoverageLevel, 
  c.CoverageType.CoveragePosition
}
```

For each distinct key in the input sequence a `CoverageOption` is created. Note that a single key may be associated with multiple `Coverage` items and for each key and one or more associated `Coverage` items the following properties of `CoverageOption` is computed:

- The `CoverageType` property is computed from the key.
- The `Limits` property is computed by taking all the `Limit` values of the associated `Coverage` items and for each distinct `Coverage.Limit.Code` pick the first `Limit` instance. So this is a sequence of `Limit` objects each having a distinct `Code`.
- The `Deductibles` property is computed by taking all the `Deductible` values of the associated `Coverage` items and for each distinct `Coverage.Deductible.Code` pick the first `Deductible` instance. So this is a sequence of `Deductible` objects each having a distinct `Code`.

Comment: Wow, this answer is so awesome. I am going through it, i am sure this would clear the clouds!! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: so the key for this ToLookup was a Tuple initially which i changed to a anonymous type as in the code above. Can you comment on this, if what i did was right? I removed tuples because i had to access the keys using items1, 2 etc which made the code unreadable.

Comment: @Charu: Instead of using an anonymous type as the key you should be able to use `CoverageType`. However, to do that you need to override `CoverageType.Equals` and `CoverageType.GetHashCode` to ensure that different instances with same property values are considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation states:

> The ToLookup(IEnumerable, Func) method returns a Lookup, a one-to-many dictionary that maps keys to collections of values. A Lookup differs from a Dictionary, which performs a one-to-one mapping of keys to single values.

so it is similar to `GroupBy` but there are some differences that are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215428/why-are-tolookup-and-groupby-different).