# How to chain Linq methods dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, method-chaining

I working with MongoDB driver and I have the following classes:

```
public class Transactions
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int SettingId { get; set; }
}
public class Account
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
}
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
}
public class Setting
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
}
```

And I want form this, depending of the input of user:

```
var docs = collection.Aggregate()
                     .Lookup("account", "AccountId", "_id", "asAccounts")
                     .Lookup("user", "UserId", "_id", "asUsers")
                     .Lookup("setting", "SettingId", "_id", "asSettings")
                     .As<BsonDocument>()
                     .ToList();
```

That is, if the user just wanna the relation with account, form this:

```
var docs = collection.Aggregate()
                         .Lookup("account", "AccountId", "_id", "asAccounts")
                         .As<BsonDocument>()
                         .ToList();
```

Or if him wanna the relation with account and user:

```
var docs = collection.Aggregate()
                         .Lookup("user", "UserId", "_id", "asUsers")
                         .Lookup("setting", "SettingId", "_id", "asSettings")
                         .As<BsonDocument>()
                         .ToList();
```

It I trying to do is form the query depending the needs of user. Just wanna know how to chain the methods in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your dynamic chain using some conditional tests to prepare the query:

```
var docs = collection.Aggregate();

if ( WantRelationWithAccount )
  docs = docs.Lookup("account", "AccountId", "_id", "asAccounts")

if ( WantRelationWithUser )
  docs = docs.Lookup("user", "UserId", "_id", "asUsers")

if ( WantSettings )
  docs = docs.Lookup("setting", "SettingId", "_id", "asSettings")

var result = docs.As<BsonDocument>().ToList();
```

But remember that order of operations in the chain is as added.

Linq queries are deferred executed, that means they are only executed when used like with a loop or a any method that causes the execution like `ToList`.

There is a linq `ToLookup` method but not `Lookup`, and it causes the query execution.

[Does ToLookup forces immediate execution of a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928613/does-tolookup-forces-immediate-execution-of-a-sequence)

Perhaps you use extension methods provided by a special framework.

In anyway, staging execution does not prevent you from create the chain as exposed previously.

Comment: I'm thinking that `Aggregate` and `Lookup`, which have meaning in Mongo, are methods that come with the MongoDB driver. Which makes me wonder: they look fluent, but is their execution truly deferred?