# Grouping objects to dictionary by property

Tags: c#

I Want to group `Files` by extensions. My `FileDto` looks like this:

```
public class FileDto
{
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do `Dictionary` (or any other collection) that will group my `files` by `Extension` (for example `".txt"`, `".doc"`) etc. I started to write some code:

```
// input.Files = IEnumerable<FileDto>

Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<FileDto>> dict = input.Files
    .GroupBy(x => x.Extension) // i want to Extension by my key (list of txts, list of docs etc)
    .ToDictionary(y => y.Key); // not working

foreach (var entry in dict)
{
    // do something with collection of files
}
```

My question is, how to group list of objects by property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can pass second parameter and cast IGrouping to enumerable

```
input.GroupBy(x => x.Extension).ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.AsEnumerable());
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var groups = input.Files
    .GroupBy(x => x.Extension)

foreach (var grp in groups)
{
    // grp.Key for the extension
    // foreach(var file in grp) for the files
}
```

Note `ToLookup` works similarly and is useful if accessing multiple times by key (you can do `var grp = lookup[key];`) but it is less "composable" in the LINQ-to-some-resource (database etc) sense. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215428/why-are-tolookup-and-groupby-different)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its really helpful to understand `IGrouping` but i want to have a dictionary ut thanks anyway!

Comment: @michasaucer then like I said: use `ToLookup`, which functions *like* a dictionary, except it is intended for key=>multiple (rather than key=>single, which is what dictionary does)